# How do I play a sound in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to play a .mp3 file in an Objective-C app being designed for use on Mac OS X Lion 10.7, not for the iPhone. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you mean Objective-C... Otherwise I'll suggest iTunes as a MP3 player, not Xcode...

Comment: @Macmade The best comment I have ever read :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at the [`NSSound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"] byReference:NO];
[sound play];
[sound release];
```

Comment: Slightly faster method (you don't even need the file extension!): [[NSSound soundNamed:@"mySound"] play];

Comment: [[NSSound soundNamed:@"mySound"] play]; // failed to work in a simple command line tool project on my machine ... the example given in the answer worked.