# List of MacOSX sound resources

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4

I'm looking for some objective-c code that outputs to NSLog the name of every available Sound resource on the current MacOSX system. I've done lots of google searches. I'm missing some key term as the searches are not turning up anything useful.
I've got code working to play a sound as long as I know the name of the sound from [How do I play a sound in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100607/how-do-i-play-a-sound-in-mac-os).

```
// Assumes #import <AppKit/AppKit.h> and the framework has been added. 
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fark" ofType:@"mp3"] byReference:NO];
[sound play];
[sound release];
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @CarlNorum Lots of google searches. I'm missing some key term as the searches are not turning up anything useful.
I've got code working to play a sound as long as I know the name of the sound.
<pre>
    // Assumes #import <AppKit/AppKit.h> and the framework has been added. 
    NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fark" ofType:@"mp3"] byReference:NO];
    [sound play];
    [sound release];
<code>

Comment: @kjtl First, get the code for NSApplicationSample from [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html). Next, go to line 111 in LoadOperation.m; in that line change the parameter `kUTTypeImage` to `kUTTypeAudio`. Next, run the application; at the top of the window that appears, click the button "Load Images..." and choose the System directory. You'll then see the name and path of every sound resource from that path. Double clicking a given entry opens the sound. I leave it to you to figure out how to route the names and paths to a log.

Comment: Thanks @trudyscousin. After following your directions I now have a list every sound resource in the system folder :-)

Cheers

Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `+[NSSound soundNamed:]` and you'll find that that method will search the following directories after looking in the application's main bundle:

```
~/Library/Sounds
/Library/Sounds
/Network/Library/Sounds
/System/Library/Sounds
```

So those would probably be good places to look for the system sounds available on your machine.

"every available Sound resource on the current MacOSX system" is a rather tall order, depending on what you mean. The system sounds will likely be found in the directories described above, but there may also be sounds inside applications that you might or might not consider to be part of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb. I realised from your answer I meant System sound resources.